# 3 layout in one activity

Tags: java, android

I would like to have multiple layout in my activity in would go in this order

```
<Linear layout
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent">

      <Constraint layout>

      <\Constraint layout>

      <Relative Layout>

      <\Relative Layout>

      <Constraint Layout>

      <\Constraint Layout>

<Linear layout\>
```

I would like for each of them to take one third of the height which is why I've chosen the Vertical linear layout
P.S. I know each layout contains more stuff in them however I don't think we need them to understand the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so what's the problem, just do that.
if you're asking about how to make them take 1/3, set the `layout_weight` attribute to 0.34, `layout_height` to 0dp in each of them and linear_layout will do the rest.

P.S : two of them will have `layout_weight = 0.34`, the third should be `1-0.34*2` which is `0.32`, or maybe one 0.34 + two 0.33, you specify the weights as you like.